# Pandas deleting rows based on same sting in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

```
Manufacturer               Buy Box Seller
0   Goli                   Goli Nutrition Inc.
1   Hanes                  3rd Street Brands
2   NaN                    Inspiring Life
3   Sports Research        Sports Research
4   Beckham Luxury Linen   Thalestris Co.
```

Hello i am using pandas DataFrame to clean this file and want to delete rows which contains the manufacturers name in the buy-box seller column.  For example row 1 will be deleted because it contains the string 'Goli' in Buy-Box seller Column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are misisng values so first replace them by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and then test if match values between columns by `not in statement` in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (df.fillna('Missing vals')
          .apply(lambda x: x['Manufacturer'] not in x['Buy Box Seller'], axis=1))
df = df[mask]
```

Comment: can you please also explain to me what actually happened here. thanks